# DraggableFlatList row looses the offset when inside placed inside scrollview along with a normal flatlist

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, drag-and-drop, react-native-draggable-flatlist

I am using react-native-draggable-flatlist inside the scrollview along with one another plain flatlist.
The single scroll works fine and even the lisr rendering.
The issue is when I am trying to drag any item inside the DraggableFlatList, initially the drag/drop works fine but the moment I scroll the page little bit, then when I try to drag it, onLongPress the item looses its offset and jumps up/down by some random(ie., 3, 4, 2 etc. ) rows and gets dropped

Code Structure

```
<ScrollView>
<View><DraggableFlatList /></View>
<View><FlatList /></View>
</ScrollView>
```